# Angular variables not appearing until editing input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some Angular demo work I have been doing for a simple node.js based chat server.

I can post the node server, but I doubt it's the problem, as the server is returning data to the page and the logs immediately.

After submitting your message to the server, it doesn't update the box below to show your message until you type in the input box again.

**Javascript**

```
angular.module('main', [])
.controller('main-div', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.hasLoggedIn = false;
    var loginName;
    $scope.messageList = [];

    $scope.login = function() {
        if ($scope.loginName) {
            // Perhaps have some validation so you can't duplicate names
            loginName = $scope.loginName;
            console.log($scope.loginName + " has logged in!");
            $scope.hasLoggedIn = true;

            // They then have the ability to send off messages once logged in
            var connection = new WebSocket("ws://"+window.location.hostname+":8081");
            // Send the loginName first, If 1st message then sets username
            // Else if not then just stores message
            connection.onopen = function () {
                console.log("Connection opened by: " + $scope.loginName)
                connection.send($scope.loginName);
                $scope.submit = function() {
                    var chatMessage = $scope.chatMessage;
                    if (chatMessage) {
                        connection.send(chatMessage);
                        $scope.chatMessage = '';
                    }
                };
            }

            connection.onmessage = function (event) {
                console.log("Got the message here");
                $scope.messageList.push(event.data);
                console.log("Pushed");
                console.log($scope.messageList);
            }

            connection.onclose = function () {
                console.log("Connection closed")
            }
            connection.onerror = function () {
                console.error("Connection error")
            }
        }
    };
})
```

**Index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Chat</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body ng-app="main">

<div class="col-md-8 col-xs-offset-2" ng-controller="main-div">
    <div ng-hide="hasLoggedIn">
        <h1>Please Login</h1>
        <form ng-submit="login()">
            <input type="text" ng-model="loginName" placeholder="Please enter your name">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-offset-2" ng-show="hasLoggedIn">
        <h1> Welcome {{loginName}}</h1>
        <div class="chat">
            <form ng-submit="submit()">
                <input type="text" ng-model="chatMessage" placeholder="Please enter a message">
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
            <div ng-repeat="message in messageList">
                {{message}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

All the console logs in the browser are appearing immediately, there is effectively no delay between me sending the message, and logs at:

```
connection.onmessage = function (event) {
                console.log("Got the message here");
                $scope.messageList.push(event.data);
                console.log("Pushed");
                console.log($scope.messageList);
            }
```

Thanks,
Oliver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try add $apply for  $scope.messageList.push(event.data), as below:

```
      connection.onmessage = function (event) {
            console.log("Got the message here");

             $scope.$apply(function() {
                 $scope.messageList.push(event.data);
             });

            console.log("Pushed");
            console.log($scope.messageList);
        }
```

Comment: Worked! I tried $scope.$apply; without the function, but it didn't work, any idea why this did? Many thanks!

Comment: Please review https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope,  "$apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events, setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of exception handling, executing watches."
WebSocket is out of angular framework, is third party libraries, so need use $apply

Comment: Ahh okay, so any refreshing of variables within the angular framework would be fine with just $scope.$apply, but this is out of the framework. Cool! Got it Thank you :)